# Locate color position on screen?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv, pyautogui

I want to click on a specific color on the screen with pyautogui, but for that I need its position, and I can't find any useful information about the topic. I'm trying to make a Piano Tiles autoclicker and for that I've thought about identifying the tiles' color and clicking it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find color position with `pyautogui`:

```
import pyautogui

color = (255, 255, 255)

s = pyautogui.screenshot()
for x in range(s.width):
    for y in range(s.height):
        if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:
            pyautogui.click(x, y)  # do something here
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider making a screenshot of smaller area to identify pixels faster.

```
pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 300, 400))
```

The argument is a four-integer tuple of the left, top, width, and height of the region to capture. You can even grab only one pixel of each tile to make it work better. I don't think making a screenshot of the whole screen would be a great idea, especially when tiles goes fast.

How I would do it:

1. use `pyautogui.position()` to get coords of one pixel of each region where tiles appears (assuming color of tile is solid and is not changing during the game)
2. use `getpixel()` to obtain the RGB values of tile pixel
3. check in loop if pixels with coordinates from step 1 have the same RGB values you obtained in step 2.
4. Call `pyautogui.click()` if yes

Answer (score 1):

This is my first post! :) I had the same problem, but I found a solution. My code is probably not following any programming standard, but it is working hahaha! I started programming in Python 2 months ago (some experience 20 years ago (QBasic/C/Java), but never anything professional). Please tell me if is working for you and if there is anything that I can improve. I hope I can help somebody with this post, since this site has been helping me so much in the last 2 months!

```py
def checkForRGBValues(start=(0,0), end=(50,50), R=255, G=255, B=255):

    x = int(end[0]-start[0] + 1)
    y = int(end[1]-start[1] + 1)
    # print(x)
    # print(y)
    for x in range(start[0], end[0] + 1, 1):
        for y in range(start[1], end[1] + 1, 1):
            print(str(x) + "/" + str(y))

            if pyautogui.pixel(x, y)[0] == R and pyautogui.pixel(x, y)[1] == G and pyautogui.pixel(x, y)[2] == B:
                print("Color found")
                with open("color_found.txt", "a") as file_found:
                    file_found.write(str(x) + "/" + str(y))
                    file_found.write("\n")
            else:

                with open("color_not_found.txt", "a") as file:
                    file.write(str(x) + "/" + str(y))
                    file.write("\n")

            y = y + 1
        x = x + 1



checkForRGBValues((150,200), (200,250), R=255, G=0, B=0) #if nothing (0,0), (50,50)
```

Comment: I have just noticed that 2 lines are not inside the code part, I am sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version that counts how many pixels are in the region:

```
import pyautogui

def checkForRGBValues(start=(0,0), end=(50,50), R=255, G=255, B=255): #start/end/r/g/b value, I put some standard values for testing

    x = int(end[0]-start[0] + 1) #calculates x value between start and end
    y = int(end[1]-start[1] + 1)  #calculates y value between start and end
    how_many_pixels_found = 0 #nothing found yet 
    for x in range(start[0], end[0] + 1, 1): #loops through x value
        for y in range(start[1], end[1] + 1, 1): #loops through y value
            if pyautogui.pixel(x, y)[0] == R and pyautogui.pixel(x, y)[1] == G and pyautogui.pixel(x, y)[2] == B: #checks if the wanted RGB value is in the region
                how_many_pixels_found = how_many_pixels_found + 1 #adds one to the result

            y = y + 1
        x = x + 1
    return how_many_pixels_found #returns the total value of pixels with the wanted color in the region.

x = checkForRGBValues((150,200), (200,250), R=60, G=63, B=65)
print(x)
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: I am sorry! I have just added the comments! I should have thought about that before posting :-)