# How can I (in Python) make a program that scans an entire image pixel by pixel, and searches for a specific color?

Tags: python, image

The color values can be in RGB or hex, I've been stuck on this for a while, so any solution is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61288717/14989075

Comment: To get pixel values from a saved image (as opposed to a screenshot), you could use PIL and `getpixel()` or OpenCV and `at()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252419/how-to-modify-the-pixel-value-of-each-pixel-conditionally-using-pil-image-only

Comment: Thank you two so much, I fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `matplotlib.image` which converts pixels of an image to np.array:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np


def searh_image_for_rgb(image_fname, rgb):
    img = mpimg.imread(image_fname)
    x, y = np.where(np.all(img == rgb, axis=2))
    return np.array([x, y]).transpose()


print(searh_image_for_rgb('example.jpg', [0, 0, 0]))
```

Comment: Thank you to you as well.